# How to fix it's. when pass non English string from ajax request to mvc controller it's change to alien's language in ie11?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax-request

When i call ajax request pass non English character string to controller it's changed to Alien's language like .
This problem is only in ie11? i test with two browser ie11 and chrome.

ps. Sorry for bad English skill?

**EDIT**

I can solve my problem by @Muhammad Omer Aslam's comment. Thank you very much.

Comment: :D can you share that alien language that is sent along with your code you are working on , before you get downvoted, add them in your original post

Comment: and i suspect that problem would be on your server side rather than javascript because it can work around with ecodeURI for converting them to UTF-8

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam. i use encodeURI(url); in my ajax request and it's work. Thank you very much.

Comment: glad to be of help